# Build container found dead before completing the build. Build container died because it was out of memory, or the Docker image was missing glibc

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, docker, xvfb, aws-codebuild

I am trying to do some basic Python Selenium tests in AWS. My idea was to have CodeBuild run them and then deploy...pretty basic, right?

However, I was having a lot of trouble with xvfb using an AWS provided image such as `aws/codebuild/python:2.7.12`

So I decided to use a docker image that the nice people at Selenium made: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/StandaloneFirefox

I ran into the issue in the title and I am fairly certain it is not because of too little RAM (I tried 3GB and 7GB).

I have also tried extending the Selenium docker file to ensure glibc is install:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:latest

RUN sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: What is the error? Where is this error being reported from? Why do you need to modify the selenium image? You would normally have a python process/container running the tests that connects to the selenium container.

Comment: As @Matt said, please include more information, especially any build logs leading up to the error.

Comment: Sort of, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I reopened the question